# Text Box validation through onkeyup event Jquery without using alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, alert

I have the following text box in my html page .

The code which I am using so far is .

```
<input type="text" id = "points" onkeyup="Validate()">
function Validate(){


var text_value = document.getElementById("points").value;
alert(text_value);

   if (!text_value.match(/^[56789]$/) && document.getElementById(called_id).value !="")
    {
       document.getElementById("points").value="";
       //  document.getElementById("points").focus(); 
       alert("Please Enter only between 5 and 10 ");
    }

}
```

Accepted values are 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 and 10 .
I have found the way based on onkeyup event to accept only 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 and 9 .. I want to know how to include 10 there .
Also I want to know the onkeyup event validation for the same using jquery .

1. If the user gives any other value apart from these it should be given to the right of the text box as "The value should be between 5 and 10 " (not as an alert) .
2. If the first entered value is 1 , it should wait for the next key pressed . Accept if it is  0 or raise the same error message as in previous case .

Comment: This is not a site where you hire developers to do the work for you (as you don't pay anyone). This a community that helps you with code. We don't build complete code for you to use. Please update your post and show us what you have tried.

Comment: I have been using alert and did for 5 to 9 . I need help in the remaining thats why I have asked

Comment: post your code here plz

Comment: I want the validation through javascript or jquery . I cant use max and min values since I am not using form tag input type= "number" box

Comment: Is `onkeyup` is mandatory for you or is it possible to use 'onblur'

Comment: I prefer onkeyup because , I want the user to know as and when he types

Answer (score 1):

[Working Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7DMH5/70/)

I would prefer without regex:

```
function validate() {
    var num = document.getElementById("points2").value;
    var num = parseInt(num, 10);
    alert(num);
    if (num < 5 || num > 10) {
        document.getElementById("points2").value = "";
        alert("Please Enter only between 5 and 10 ");
    }
}
```

change your regex to :

```
/^([5-9]|10)$/
```

you should use `onchange` event:

```
<input type="text" id = "points"  onchange="Validate()">

function Validate(){    
var text_value = document.getElementById("points").value;
alert(text_value);

   if (!text_value.match(/^([5-9]|10)$/) && document.getElementById(called_id).value !="")
    {
       document.getElementById("points").value="";
       //  document.getElementById("points").focus(); 
       alert("Please Enter only between 5 and 10 ");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks , but is it not possible with onkeyup , because I want changes to be done without the focus is moved to another element .

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#textbox').keyup(function() {
    var value = $('#textbox').val();
    if(value != ''){
        if(!value.match(/^[5678910]$/))  
            textboxError();
        else{
            var length = value.length;
            if(value.charAt(length-1) == 0 && value.charAt(length-2) != 1)
                textboxError();
        }
    }
};

$('#textbox').change(function() {
    var value = $('#textbox').val();
    if(value != '')
        textboxError();
    }
};

function textboxError(){
    $('#textbox').val(''); 
    $('#textbox').focus(); 
    alert("Please Enter only between 5 and 10 ");
}
```

What we are doing is,

1. Check if value is empty (If empty don't perform anything)
2. If not empty check if the value matches to defined set
3. If it match, now we do check for 10. What we do is if last entered item of field is 0, than the previous field must be 1 so it makes a 10. If not we throw error.
4. But here is a problem, the user might enter 1 and leave the field without entering another char. So, u can extend this by onchange field.
5. Onchange, now we check for count of 1 and that should match count of 10. It fixes our problem. You don't have to worry of 0 because we already check it in keyup block.

I Didn't check the code. So if any typos or errors, u can replace them.

Comment: I had a similar regex previously , but this allows 0 too .

Answer (score 0):

As Zaheer Ahmed stated, `/^([5-9]|10)$/` will catch 10 as well.  For the event listener, you can use

```
$('#textbox')[0].addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  var value = $(event.target).val();  
  // we already have a reference to the element through the event object,
  // crawling the DOM again is expensive.

  if(value != '') textboxError();
});
```

This bypasses jQuery, which may be frowned upon by some, but the 'input' event fires immediately and also works if the text was pasted in or entered by some other method.